# Check if dict key is a substring of any other element in the dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I've got a dictionary **ngram_list** as follows:

```
ngram_list = dict_items([
    ('back to back breeding', {'wordcount': 4, 'count': 3}),
    ('back breeding', {'wordcount': 2, 'count': 5}),
    ('several consecutive heats', {'wordcount': 3, 'count': 2}),
    ('how often should', {'wordcount': 3, 'count': 2}),
    ('often when breeding', {'wordcount': 3, 'count': 1})
])
```

I want to sort the list from the shortest wordcount to the largest and then loop through the dictionary and if the key is a substring of any other item, delete it (the substring item.)

Expected output:

```
ngram_list = dict_items([
    ('several consecutive heats', {'wordcount': 3, 'count': 2}),
    ('how often should', {'wordcount': 3, 'count': 2}),
    ('often when breeding', {'wordcount': 3, 'count': 1}),
    ('back to back breeding', {'wordcount': 4, 'count': 3})
])
```

Comment: what is your final expected output dictionary ?

Comment: @Skycc updated sorry

Comment: so you want your output as dictionary or list of tuples like dict.items() return ? You will needed `OrderedDict` for the items sorted in order

Comment: Do you also want to replace is one key is a substring of another, but a different word? As in "cat" and "catastrophe"?

Comment: @tobias_k only full words/ngrams/expressions, not parts of a word

Comment: @Skycc the output is not that important, but as a dictionary ideally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter the input dict to get rid of unwanted items, then using [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function with key to sort the items by wordcount, and finally build the dict with [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Using simple `in` to check for substring only, might need to use `regex` if wanna take care exact full word boundary match

```
from collections import OrderedDict
ngram_dict = {
    'back to back breeding': {'wordcount': 4, 'count': 3},
    'back breeding': {'wordcount': 2, 'count': 5},
    'several consecutive heats': {'wordcount': 3, 'count': 2},
    'how often should': {'wordcount': 3, 'count': 2},
    'often when breeding': {'wordcount': 3, 'count': 1}
}

# ngram items with unwanted items filter out
ngram_filter = [i for i in ngram_dict.items() if not any(i[0] in k and i[0] != k for k in ngram_dict.keys())]
final_dict = OrderedDict( sorted(ngram_filter, key=lambda x:x[1].get('wordcount')) )

# final_dict = OrderedDict([('several consecutive heats', {'count': 2, 'wordcount': 3}), ('how often should', {'count': 2, 'wordcount': 3}), ('often when breeding', {'count': 1, 'wordcount': 3}), ('back to back breeding', {'count': 3, 'wordcount': 4})])
```

All this can be fitted into 1 liner as below

```
from collections import OrderedDict
final_dict = OrderedDict( 
sorted((i for i in ngram_dict.items() if not any(i[0] in k and i[0] != k for k in ngram_dict.keys())), 
key=lambda x:x[1].get('wordcount')) )
```